# product page image upload shows "Upload HTTP Error"

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

whenever i try to upload an image on product page it gives this error:

```
Upload HTTP Error
```

Given all permissions to all the required folders and cleared cache.

Any solution?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using PHP 7  then go to

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

Find the following code

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

And replace it with

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check apache error log.as well as ask your hosting provider if PHP is running in FastCGI mode and if there is MaxRequestLen limitation.

Comment: already checked this isn't working for me

Comment: .htaccess and .htpasswd issue i think

Comment: means what kind of issue?

Comment: have you protected directory with password

Comment: which directory?

Comment: media folder http error

Comment: nope media folder is not password protected

Comment: have you re-indexed ?

Comment: yes its is re-indexed

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below link in which given the steps to follow to solve this error:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994648/magento-upload-http-error
Possible to try all this steps.

Answer (score 0):

You may have exceeded the file size or dimensions that are set. I've had this error before when trying to upload an image that's several MB. Try a test image less than 500k. If it works, then try adjusting your PHP settings to something like the below:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 10M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a permission problem or you have to increase

```
upload_max_filesize 
post_max_filesize
```

in the php.ini file.