# Magento 1 & PHP 7.0

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

We are currently using **PHP 5.6** which is nearing end of life. Are **Magento 1.9.2.3** and **Magento 1.9.2.4** compatible with **PHP 7.0**? If not, what changes are necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Magento 1.9.2.3 and Magento 1.9.2.4 compatible with PHP 7.0

there is some change required in core file

1 Here is my old answer for image upload issue in magento with php 7

[product page image upload shows "Upload HTTP Error"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86127/product-page-image-upload-shows-upload-http-error/146213#146213)

go to

```
lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
```

Find the following code

```
$params['object']->$params['method']($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

And replace it with

```
$params['object']->{$params['method']}($this->_file['tmp_name']);
```

and 2 go to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php
```

find following code

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

and replace it with

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

Comment: "Yes Magento 1.9.2.3 and Magento 1.9.2.4 compatible with PHP 7.0". No ,it's not.

Answer (score 1):

> We are currently using PHP 5.6 which is nearing end of life.

PHP 5.6 will be supported until 1 Jan 2019. So there is no need to switch to php7 except you want to profit from the performance benefits.

There are more incompatibilities that need to be fixed and discovered. Even if you fix magento core for php7 then you still have to struggle around with extensions you use.

So if you have a fixed/small budget for that, I won't recommend changing the php version right now. Otherwise, feel free to experiment at your project.