# Help uploading pictures - keeps coming up error

Tags: image-upload

I'm a newbie to magento, i have had a designer build site and now i am trying to add extra products and having a few issues. The first issue is i cant add a product image it comes up with error, i have used chrome, firefox, changed wording on image and size format. What a i doing wrong please. I am currently selecting images from my desktop.

Thank you in advance

[image: this same code comes up on every picture ive tried]

Comment: This link will be helpful: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86127/product-page-image-upload-shows-upload-http-error

Comment: thank you i dont understand what all those code paths are? A designer created website and gave me admin login details so i have nothing downloaded on mac. i do also have a one.com to host, i can see pictures they have put on website in there, so do i have to get them from there somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to check in server. One more note, you can check the server's error_log, exception.log to get the details and cause of the error.